# Constraint layout admob issue

Tags: java, android, admob, android-constraintlayout

I am new to android programming and I do not know many things yet. What I am trying to achieve here is something like this. If the user does not have internet connection the ads dont show up or if the ads for some reason does not load then the ads dont show up. But the layout does remains the same meaning the ad space is left empty. What I did was warp the ad view in inside of a Relative Layout and then created a function which checks if the ads are loaded or not then changes the visibility of the layout, this seems to work and solve the blank space issues when ads does not load. But I think that this is not best way to do this and there must be a better way.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admobTest.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btnExit"
        ads:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnViewBuildProp"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewBuildProp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btnViewBuildProp"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeAdsLayout"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvStatus"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvDeviceInfo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnViewBuildProp"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txvStatus" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeAdsLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnExit">


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="@string/adSize"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="457dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** only relevant bits

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showAds(true); // this displays the ads 

      }
    private void showAds(Boolean doShowAds) {
        RelativeLayout relativeAdsLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeAdsLayout);

        if (doShowAds.equals(true)) {
            mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            relativeAdsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (doShowAds.equals(false)) {
            relativeAdsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } //end showAds
} //end class
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Leave a comment rather than leaving a down vote for no reason.

Comment: What weaknesses in your current solution are you looking solve? Are you looking for an admob API method to solve this? Side note, why are you using `Boolean` objects instead of `boolean` primitives?

Comment: If there is an admob API for this then yes. And the answer to your second question is  because I am a Noob.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the AdView at all if the user has no internet connection. 
Also an ad request should be avoided, if you know the user has no proper internet connection.

If the ad request fails you could remove the AdView from the Layout or try an other add request as often as you want.

You might also add some progress or an other background view (or image, progress etc.), wile the ad loads or if the user has no internet

Comment: I am seen in many apps that when the user has no internet the layout goes full screen even filling the space that was left for the ads. And when the user has internet the ads show up and the layout moves up to make space for the ad. I wanted to do something similar. Thats the reason I created the function which hides the ads and as a result expands the layout. I was just thinking if there were any better solution thats all.

Screen shot of the default behavior: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/wFySk)